# What is easiest solution for twisted cable connection between two PCs running Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ethernet

I plan to change OS on my other PC from Windows XP to Ubuntu and want to have access to it.

Basically please imagine two PCs, each running Ubuntu 11.04 and connected together with twisted cable ([Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)).
I want to be able to access filesystems in both directions (from either PC to other) in the easiest possible way.

---

**update**: I just installed Ubuntu (decided to dual-boot as first), and the process went flawlessly, Gparted resized partions with ease and overall everything was smooth, which I did not expect when computer tasks are in question.

Comment: Well if you had a router and were connected locally, I'd use ssh and sshfs.  ssh for opening a terminal on the other PC, and sshfs for mounting the other PC on a mountpoint.  However, I don't know what kind of networking you can have via a twisted ethernet.. but as long as you can reach the other PC via a IP like 192.168.1.85, then SSH should work

Comment: No router, just cable connecting two Ethernet cards. I have not yet removed XP, so can't try your suggestion, but it looks promising if I can just use `sshfs` to mount filesystems around

Comment: Yup.  Looks like you have 192.168.1.x IPs.  I believe ssh should be already installed, so install sshfs: `sudo apt-get install sshfs`.  now on the 192.168.1.1 computer: `sshfs root@192.168.1.2:/home/USER/ ~/MountDir`, and on 192.168.1.2: `sshfs root@192.168.1.1:/home/USER/ ~/MountDir`.  To make this easier, you could create a script and place it in /usr/games/, and run `chmod +x scriptname`, then you can mount it with one command. You can also go one step further by going to the startup applications, and adding your script [/usr/games/scriptname] :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the 2 pcs directly using a cross network cable and use the `ifconfig` command to assign the fixed addresses between the pcs.

ie:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

for pc1, and

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

for pc 2, where eth0 is your network interface name (check `ifconfig -a` for all your interfaces).

Use `ping` to see if you have connection between pcs: from pc1 > `ping 192.168.1.2`, from pc2 > `ping 192.168.1.1`

If you can ping you can connect, the use of `NFS` is really simple and fast to use, check it here: [Ubuntu NFS howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)

Comment: This worked on first try, `ping` command was success. Linked page (NFS) is a bit more complicated then expected and I did't try it as I have other problem this way. Main PC has wireless Internet connection through USB stick, and connection dropped, which made me think, if it's possible to make other PC (which most of the time is headless) be accessible from this Main PC and not the other way around, so I can keep Internet connection perhaps?

Comment: Then you need to assign your main computer as a router: 'wireless ----> internet, eth0 ------> internal net'.

Comment: Yes, Wireless uses "Automatic DHCP" method. What parameters are you suggesting to change? Can I set that workflow with NetworkManager dialog?

Comment: type: `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`, edit/add line `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`, do a `/etc/init.d/network restart`, use iptables to setup ip forwarding and masquerading with `iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wireless -j MASQUERADE` and `iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Where wireless is your internet USB interface and eth0 is your wired LAN to the other PC, you need to find the names of the interfaces with `ifconfig -a` and change that on the instructions.

Comment: If this works tell me so we can use iptables save command so that the settings don't go away every time you reboot.

Comment: I changed `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, then rebooted as I couldn't find `network` command. I made script with your `iptables` commands but I'm not sure if you are suggesting I change some words in it so here is output from `ifconfig -a`: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aqUvVykr

Comment: `iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlan0 -j MASQUERADE` and `iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT` should be the rules for iptables. Wlan0 should be left with DHCP and eth0 with static address, on your 2nd pc no need to do anything as long as eth0 is static and assigned.

Comment: After that you should be able to `ping www.google.com` and `ping 2ndpcaddress` from your main pc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your walk-through, but unfortunately `ping 192.168.1.2` outputs `Destination Host Unreachable`

Comment: Give the ifconfig -a of the 2nd pc. After this is done you wont have to worry about it anymore so dont quit just yet ;) If you think this is too tricky maybe some hardware investment will be a better option, since you have 2 different networks why not get a switch, connect your 2 pcs to the switch and your switch to the router via PoE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) and your are done? Its much faster then wireless and you would not need this all configuration because your router would handle all the addresses with DHCP.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=V31Cps55 Thanks for you suggestion, I'll think about it

Comment: eth0 on the main pc (pc1) is set to a different range from pc2: pc1 ip address in eth0 is 10.42.43.1 and on pc2 is 192.168.1.2. Fix that on the eth0 interface of pc1 and try again. `ifconfig -a` should read: `inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0` and on pc2 should be the way it is at the moment: `inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0'

Comment: To fix it use the same command on pc1 I posted on the first comment: `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255`. After that check ifconfig again to see if the IP is correctly set now.

Comment: internet connection drops if I issue that command

Comment: Ok, I found an article that describes your current setup and how to make all the pcs connected to the same network using your wlan0 as a connection to the router. Have a look and let me know if that helped: [InternetConnectionSharing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing). Have in mind that this way your 2nd pc will also be connected to the internet! Revert back all the changes we have done until now and try it. Hope it works ;)

Comment: Found why your internet connection goes down, you wlan0 in your 1st pc is already taking your 192.168.1.255 range of addresses, you can also follow what I said till now but instead of using `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255` for pc1 and `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255` for pc2 you need to use another range of addresses like: `ifconfig eth0 100.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 100.0.0.255` for pc1 and `ifconfig eth0 100.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 100.0.0.255` for pc2!

Comment: Excellent Bruno! I wish you were near to buy you a beer ;) Everything works perfectly now ^_^

Comment: ;) have fun and if you need any other stuff ask and you shall receive! *BEER UP*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In the future please edit your post with new information instead of [posting it in the comments section](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1693/moving-question-related-discussions-from-comments-to-chat-seems-pointless-destro/1695#1695) :) This prevents users from having to read the entire discussion to get all the facts.

Answer (score 0):

Just Connect the two PCs with UTP and give each unique IP address. Then you can share folders and access them from Nautilus. I have done this from ubuntu to windows using samba and I don't have reason why it should not work with ubuntu.
So share the folders that you need to be accessible to both PCs

Comment: Maybe a software layer is required at least on one of the two PSs: ssh or ftp server, or samba server (if you don't want to recur to `netcat`)

Comment: I installed Samba on both PCs ad shared folders on both, but I couldn't see other PC. Tried to set `eth0` IPv4 method to "shared" then "manual" with fixed IP address w/o success. I probably miss something